# Упростить метод, который возвращает статистику по коллекции

Tags: java, коллекции, map

Есть метод надо сократить до двух циклов for. Один для загрузки данных, а второй для поиска в этой карте элементов второго списка. Есть мысли как это сделать?

```
package ru.job4j.store;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Store {

    /**
     * Метод считает кол-во изменений в коллекции.
     * <p>
     * Метод работает следующим образом:
     * Если кол-во ключей из прошлой коллекции больше чем у новой растет счетчик добавления элементов.
     * Если кол-во ключей из прошлой коллекции меньше чем у новой растет счетчик удаления элементов.
     * Если ключи не эквивалентные то растет счетчик изменений.
     *
     * @param previous - прежняя коллекция.
     * @param current  - новоя коллекция.
     * @return карту с счетчиками.
     */
    public HashMap<String, Integer> isChange(List<User> previous, List<User> current) {
        int newAdd = 0;
        int newChange = 0;
        int newDelete = 0;

        Map<Integer, String> mapOfPrevious = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer, String> mapOfCurrent = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();

        for (User indexPrevious : previous) {
            mapOfPrevious.put(indexPrevious.getId(), indexPrevious.getName());
        }

        for (User indexCurrent : current) {
            mapOfCurrent.put(indexCurrent.getId(), indexCurrent.getName());
        }

        for (Integer key : mapOfPrevious.keySet()) {
            if (!mapOfCurrent.containsKey(key)) {
                newDelete++;
            } else if (!mapOfCurrent.get(key).equals(mapOfPrevious.get(key))) {
                newChange++;
            }
        }

        for (Integer key : mapOfCurrent.keySet()) {
            if (!mapOfPrevious.containsKey(key)) {
                newAdd++;
            }
        }

        result.put("Amount new add: ", newAdd);
        result.put("Amount new change: ", newChange);
        result.put("Amount new delete: ", newDelete);

        return result;
    }

    static class User {
        private int id;

        private String name;

        public User(int id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос был решен так:

```
package ru.job4j.store;
```

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class Store {

```
/**
 * Метод считает кол-во изменений в коллекции.
 *
 * @param previous - прежняя коллекция.
 * @param current  - новоя коллекция.
 * @return карту с счетчиками.
 */
public HashMap<String, Integer> isChange(List<User> previous, List<User> current) {
    int deleteCount = 0;
    int changeCount = 0;
    int beforeSize = previous.size();

    HashMap<Integer, String> allUsers = new HashMap<>();

    for (User index : current) {
        allUsers.put(index.getId(), index.getName());
    }

    for (User index : previous) {
        if (!allUsers.containsKey(index.getId())) {
            deleteCount++;
        } else if (!allUsers.get(index.getId()).equals(index.getName())) {
            changeCount++;
        }
        allUsers.put(index.getId(), index.getName());
    }

    int newListSize = allUsers.size();
    HashMap<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();


    result.put("Amount new add: ", newListSize - beforeSize);
    result.put("Amount new change: ", changeCount);
    result.put("Amount new delete: ", deleteCount);

    return result;
}

static class User {
    private int id;

    private String name;

    public User(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

}

Вот здесь можно можно посмотреть тест на него:

https://github.com/AlexandarVysotskiy/AVysotskiy/commit/1479aac7301a200f5611c81e002d342f44359e36

Answer (score 1):

Сначала возьмем количество старых и данных, пришедших к обновлению:

```
int beforeSize = previous.size();
int afterSize = current.size();
```

Добавляем всех юзеров сразу в один список:

```
List<User> allUsers = new ArrayList<>();
allUsers.addAll(previous);
allUsers.addAll(current);
```

И разбросам в карту. При дублировании ключа меняется его значение, это можно использовать для получения карты с уже измененными данными:

```
Map<Integer, String> usersMap = new HashMap<>();
for (User user : allUsers) { 
    usersMap.put(user.getId(), user.getName());
}
```

Далее получим размер этой карты:

```
int newListSize = usersMap.size();
```

Теперь у нас есть три числа: сколько пар пришло как "новые", сколько было и сколько стало. Исходя из этих данных можно получить кол-во новых, кол-во измененных и кол-во удаленных.

```
int newAdd = Math.max(0, newListSize -  beforeSize);
int newChange = Math.max(0, afterSize - newAdd);
int newDelete = Math.max(0, newListSize - newAdd - newChange);
```

Comment: Автор дал полный код, почему вы, даете кусками, непонятно, следовательно если автор не поймет, будут следовать очередные вопросы, куда, зачем почему. Следовательно, нужно давать полный код, изменив код автора.

Comment: @And, чтобы автор не просто скопипастил его себе а прочитал и понял. Если вы не заметили я по частям код обьясняю, иначе это бы был идиотизм

Comment: @And, если хотите - внесите правку, я приму

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Объяснили как надо. Но ваш код не до конца рабочий. Вот здесь:

Comment: int newDelete = Math.max(0, beforeSize - afterSize);

Comment: Почему размер предыдущей коллекции - размер общий = размер удаленных?

Comment: Я решил это так: число удаленных = общее число - число измененных - число новых. Т.е. newDelete = afterSize - newAdd  - newChange .

Comment: Если кому интересен весь код с тестом вам сюда: https://github.com/AlexandarVysotskiy/AVysotskiy/commit/725cc2084f2030101b561d4ec2dfbb996a68ea14

Comment: Там у вас вроде нет защиты от отрицательных значений. Я бы конечные данные вынес в переменные и там бы использовал `Math.max(0, ` а затем уже набил ими карту

Comment: Если мой ответ вам помог отметьте его верным поставив галочку слева

Comment: Плюс в вынесении конечных переменных еще в том что можно их друг за другом использовать. Вы же указали вычисления сразу при вставке в карту и так как не можете обратиться к предыдущим переменным дублируется код

Comment: Я пересмотрел код. Видимо отрицательные значения невозможно получить)